# Blocking duplicate http request using mod security

Tags: apache, httprequest, mod-security, mod-security2, http-status-code-409

I am using mod security to look for specific values in post parameters  and blocking the request if duplicate comes in. I am using mod security user collection to do just that. The problem is that my requests are long running so a single request can take in more than 5 minutes. The user collection i assume does not get written to disk until the first request gets processed. If during the execution of the first request another request comes in using the duplicate value for post parameter the second request does not gets blocked since the collection is not available yet. I need to avoid this situation. Can I use memory based shared collections across requests in mod security? Any other way? Snippet below:

```
SecRule ARGS_NAMES "uploadfilename" "id:400000,phase:2,nolog,setuid:%{ARGS.uploadfilename},initcol:USER=%{ARGS.uploadfilename},setvar:USER.duplicaterequests=+1,expirevar:USER.duplicaterequests=3600" 
SecRule USER:duplicaterequests "@gt 1" "id:400001,phase:2,deny,status:409,msg:'Duplicate Request!'" 

ErrorDocument 409 "<h1>Duplicate request!</h1><p>Looks like this is a duplicate request, if this is not on purpose, your original request is most likely still being processed. If this is on purpose, you'll need to go back, refresh the page, and re-submit the data."
```

Answer (score 1):

ModSecurity is really not a good place to put this logic.

As you rightly state there is no guarantee when a collection is written, so even if collections were otherwise reliable (which they are not - see below), you shouldn't use them for absolutes like duplicate checks. They are OK for things like brute force or DoS checks where, for example, stopping after 11 or 12 checks rather than 10 checks isn't that big a deal. However for absolute checks, like stopping duplicates, the lack of certainty here means this is a bad place to do this check. A WAF to me should be an extra layer of defence, rather than be something you depend on to make your application work (or at least stop breaking). To me, if a duplicate request causes a real problem to the transactional integrity of the application, then those checks belong in the application rather than in the WAF.

In addition to this, the disk based way that collections work in ModSecurity, causes lots of problems - especially when multiple processes/threads try to access them at once - which make them unreliable both for persisting data, and for removing persisted data. Many folks on the [ModSecurity](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mod-security-users) and [OWASP ModSecurity CRS](https://lists.owasp.org/mailman/listinfo/owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set) mailing lists have seen errors in the log file when ModSecurity tried to automatically  clean up collections, and so have seen collections files grow and grow until it starts to have detrimental effects on Apache. In general I don't recommend user collections for production usage - especially for web servers with any volume.

There was a [memcache version of ModSecurity created that was created](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/378) which stopped using the dusk based SDBM format which may have addressed a lot of the above issues however it was not completed, [though it may be part of ModSecurity v3](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/1140). I still disagree however that a WAF is the place to check this.